# How to select values from two tables in mysql prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

For adding database I am using PhpMyAdmin in Xampp server.  I have created two tables and each table contains different rows. I am trying to select values from two tables at the same time in php. The following code works fine

```
    $gi1=2;

    $stmt2=$this->con->prepare(" SELECT qwer  FROM table1  WHERE nmnm=?;");
    $stmt2->bind_param("i",$gi1);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($var1);
    $stmt2->fetch();

    $gi2=23;

    $stmt2=$this->con->prepare(" SELECT qwer2  FROM table2  WHERE nmnm2=?;");
    $stmt2->bind_param("i",$gi2);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($var2);
    $stmt2->fetch();
```

But it takes too much time so I decided it to select in one statement.

```
$gi2=23;$gi1=2;

    $stmt2=$this->con->prepare(" SELECT qwer2,qwer1  FROM table2,table1  WHERE nmnm2=? or nmnm=?;");
    $stmt2->bind_param("ii",$gi2,$gi1);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($var2,$var1);
    $stmt2->fetch();
```

And it shows a fatal error.So how can I select values from two tables in one statement?

Comment: Two queries are fine here. You might just need an index.

Comment: You can't just slam two queries together like that, they must be *related*. There's ways to do this with `UNION` but it's usually not worth the fuss. Do two queries, combine the results. If it takes "too much time" you need to optimize the query, as combining queries always makes things slower. This usually boils down to having index coverage on the columns referenced in `WHERE`. Use `EXPLAIN` to see the potential costs of each query.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `;` is a delimiter used by interactive SQL shells and should not be included in programmatic SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

if the tables do not have any link columns you can try with UNION

```
SELECT qwer  FROM table1  WHERE nmnm=?
union
(SELECT qwer2 as qwer  FROM table2  WHERE nmnm2=?)
```